# How Compare and fetch the data from two dictionary items in Python

Tags: python

I want to fetch the data by comparing two dict items in python:

dict1:

```
rawdata = {
"node1":["id1",["set1a"]],
"node2":["id2",["set1b"]]
  }
```

dict2:

```
subdata = {
"info1":["set1a","id1","firstset","firstsection"]
"info2":["set1b","id2","secondset","secondsection"]
}
```

As one can see the raw data has the subdata values but not the complete information. I want to compare **dict1** with **dict2** to get the complete details and print the output to another dictionary like:

```
"node1":"id1","set1a","firstset","firsstsection",
"node2":"id2","set1b","secondset","secondsection"
```

By using prettytable, I want to print the information fetched from the final dictionary in tabular format. Could someone help me to solve this.

Comment: Your dict2 (`subdata`) and the desired output are no valid python...

Answer (score 0):

It could be done with a dict comprehension, but let's do it in a loop for the sake of readability :)

```
for rdk, rdv in rawdata.items():
    sdv = next((x for x in subdata.values() if x[1] == rdv[0]))
    outd[rdk] = [sdv[1], sdv[0], sdv[2], sdv[3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it more generic:

```
from pprint import pprint

rawdata = {
    "node1": ["id1", ["set1a"]],
    "node2": ["id2", ["set1b"]]
}

subdata = {
    "info1": ["set1a", "id1", "firstset", "firstsection"],
    "info2": ["set1b", "id2", "secondset", "secondsection"]
}

res = {}
for k, v in rawdata.items():
    # retrieve the ID
    id_ = v[0]
    
    # Check that in 'subdata'
    for k1, v1 in subdata.items():
        if id_ in v1:
            
            # Because in next line we want to get all of 'subdata' values all together.
            v1.remove(id_)
            res[k] = (id_, *v1)
            
            # Make subsequent searches efficient by not researching same keys  
            del subdata[k1]
            break

pprint(res)
```

output :

```
{'node1': ('id1', 'set1a', 'firstset', 'firstsection'),
 'node2': ('id2', 'set1b', 'secondset', 'secondsection')}
```